# Reportbuilder 3.0 Count number of occurrences

Tags: counter, reportbuilder3.0

I have a field that contains the "#" in a diffrent times. I want to count how many times the "#" occures int this fields.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try, **untested**:

```
=Split(Fields!Value.Value, "#").Length - 1
```